# Beautiful Soup 4 CSS selector does not work the same way the tutorial show

Tags: python, html, css, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I run the *sample CSS selector* codes from [Beautiful Soup 4 tutorial page][1], but the results are different, some give the correct result, some do not. In the website, they say it should work the same way in Python 2.7 and 3. I have Python 2.7 and **install Beautiful Soup 4.** Does anyone have the same issue?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

My test (of course I use the same html doc in the tutorial):

```
soup.select("#link1 ~ .sister")
[]
```

Their test:

```
soup.select("#link1 ~ .sister")
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie"  id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

[Click Here to See](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Could you show us your `soup` variable initialization ?

Comment: ok, I just edited the question

Comment: Just tried your code, it works for me. Did you install beautiful soup using pip ?

Comment: No, I downloaded the source tarball and run $python setup.py install

Comment: I have the same problem @HoangPham. Working to give you a solution. I installed with `pip`.

Comment: I fixed your problem, its because you're using a version below 4.3.2

Comment: Your first link is missing.

Comment: BoltClock: no I did put the link, but someone edited the question to change that. I see no reason why, you can see it from the version history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured out your problem. You are using a version of BeautifulSoup that is older than 4.3.2.

I just had 4.1.2 installed, and I ran your code. I had the same problem, I got an empty list, now that I've updated it to 4.3.2, I get the list of siblings again.

You *can* install it via pip, but you can also get the latest [version from Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2) and download it.

Comment: Wow, great, it works! Thanks alot. I thought I downloaded the latest version, as I follow the tutorial to the download page of BeautifulSoup package. Thanks.

Comment: The tutorial page links to the download site that does not have the latest version.

Comment: Same problem here using python3.4 and bs4.4 :s