# Beautiful Soup 4 CSS sibling selector

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse some HTML exported from an InDesign document with Beatiful Soup 4 abd Python 2.7.  I am trying to find a specific tag by using a CSS sibling selector.  I am able to access the tag I want by selecting its sibling via a CSS selector and then using the Beautiful Soup `find_next_sibling()` method, but I can't select it directly via a CSS selector.

I have verified that the selector itself is valid  when I try it in pure CSS/JS (http://jsfiddle.net/Sj63x/1/).  I have tried using all three parsers recommended on the Beautiful Soup home page as well.

Relevant code is posted below (text is in the JS fiddle):

```
text = BeautifulSoup(text)

'''this finds the sibling'''
sibling = text.select(".Book-Title-") 
print(sibling[0].string)

'''this finds the sibling I am looking for'''
targetText = sibling[0].find_next_sibling()
print(targetText.string)

'''This should find the same text but returns an empty list'''
targetText2 = text.select(".Book-Title- ~.Text")
print(targetText2)

'''Other attempted variations - also return empty lists'''
targetText3 = text.select(".Book-Title- ~ .Text")
targetText4 = text.select(".Book-Title- + .Text")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this selector instead:

```
targetText2 = text.select(".Book-Title- + .Text")
```

or add a space between the tilde character and the sibling:

```
targetText2 = text.select(".Book-Title- ~ .Text")
```

Comment: Thanks.  Both of those return empty lists, like the original selector.  I've added them to the question.

Comment: Strange, I have not tested the code myself though. Are you running the latest version of beautifulsoup? There seems to be some problems with CSS selectors in older versions (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516341/beautiful-soup-4-css-selector-does-not-work-the-same-way-the-tutorial-show)

Comment: If you're trying to print this: `[<span class="Text"> (December 1982)</span>]` then HAL's second line works fine.

Comment: It was the BeautifulSoup version - the one available from apt-get is an older version.  Uninstalling and updating via pip worked.