# How to get all links from page in DOM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I use beautifulsoup in Python that to get all links:

```
links = soup.select('.cover > .card-click-target')
        print(links);
```

But it gives me an array with one element and string value.

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="cover">
  <div class="cover-image-container"> 
    <div class="cover-outer-align"> 
      <div class="cover-inner-align"> 
        <img alt="Kate Mobile Lite" class="cover-image" data-cover-large="" data-cover-small="" src="" aria-hidden="true"> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a class="card-click-target" href="/s/kate_new_6" aria-label=" Kate Mobile Lite     ">
    <span class="movies preordered-overlay-container id-preordered-overlay-container" style="display:none"> 
      <span class="preordered-label">Предзаказ</span>
    </span> 
    <span class="preview-overlay-container">  </span>  
  </a> 
</div>

<div class="cover"> 
  <div class="cover-image-container">
    <div class="cover-outer-align">
      <div class="cover-inner-align"> 
        <img alt="Kate Mobile Lite" class="cover-image" data-cover-large="" data-cover-small="" src="" aria-hidden="true">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <a class="card-click-target" href="/s/kate_new_6" aria-label=" Kate Mobile Lite     ">
    <span class="movies preordered-overlay-container id-preordered-overlay-container" style="display:none">
      <span class="preordered-label">Предзаказ</span>
    </span>
    <span class="preview-overlay-container"> 
    </span>  
  </a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Without looking at the actual source of the page it's really hard to help, but if you are looking for links (which are `a` tags) you should probably use `find_all('a')`.

Comment: Look please question again, I made changes

Comment: I don't see any change

Comment: Now I see the changes and there is **only** 1 link there... what do you expect?

Comment: I did not want to duplicate this code. So, there a lot of code with `<div class="cover">`

Comment: Are you sure that all `.card-click-target` elements are **direct child** of `.cover` elements? Because this is what you search for.

Comment: Yes, `card-click-target` is inside block

Comment: Maybe I need to use `>` selector?

Comment: Did you check my example? Why not use `find_all('a.card-click-target')`?

Comment: I need to specify more concretely, with `.cover`. because there a lot  `.card-click-target` on pages

Comment: maybe they are not **direct child** of the `.cover` element?

Comment: You can see example in question

Comment: Can I use: find_all(".cover > a.card-click-target") ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: It geves me empty array[] `links = soup.find_all(".cover > a.card-click-target")`

Comment: Are you sure this is the html you search against?

Comment: doubled check and you should use the `select` (and not the `find_all` function. Your `select` should work if your html code is correct.

Comment: Yes I am sure, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_="card-click-target")
links = [i.get('href') for i in link_tags]
```

out:

```
['/s/kate_new_6', '/s/kate_new_6']
```

select version :

```
link_tags = soup.select('.cover .card-click-target')
links =[i.get('href') for i in link_tags]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to set parent like as? `.cover > card-click-target`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't fully trust CSS selector in BeautifulSoup, just a quick search you'll find [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517578/402197) talked about updating BeautifulSoup fixed the problem he had.

I would highly recommend you [write a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to do the job

```
links = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.parent.get('class', None) == ['cover'] \
                       and tag.get('class', None) == ['card-click-target'])
```

The anonymous lambda function will search for all tags with class of `card-click-target` and also make sure those tags have a parent with class of `cover`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
>>> s = """    <div class="cover">
       <div class="cover-image-container">
         <div class="cover-outer-align">
           <div class="cover-inner-align">
             <img alt="Kate Mobile Lite" class="cover-image" data-cover-large="" data-cover-small="" src="" aria-hidden="true">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <a class="card-click-target" href="/s/kate_new_6" aria-label=" Kate Mobile Lite     ">
         <span class="movies preordered-overlay-container id-preordered-overlay-container" style="display:none">
           <span class="preordered-label">Предзаказ</span>
         </span>
         <span class="preview-overlay-container">  </span>
       </a>
     </div>

     <div class="cover">
       <div class="cover-image-container">
         <div class="cover-outer-align">
           <div class="cover-inner-align">
             <img alt="Kate Mobile Lite" class="cover-image" data-cover-large="" data-cover-small="" src="" aria-hidden="true">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <a class="card-click-target" href="/s/kate_new_6" aria-label=" Kate Mobile Lite     ">
         <span class="movies preordered-overlay-container id-preordered-overlay-container" style="display:none">
           <span class="preordered-label">Предзаказ</span>
         </span>
         <span class="preview-overlay-container">
         </span>
       </a>
     </div>"""
>>> sp = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> sp.select(".cover > a.card-click-target")
[<a aria-label=" Kate Mobile Lite     " class="card-click-target" href="/s/kate_new_6">
 <span class="movies preordered-overlay-container id-preordered-overlay-container" style="display:none">
 <span class="preordered-label">?????????</span>
 </span>
 <span class="preview-overlay-container"> </span>
 </a>,
 <a aria-label=" Kate Mobile Lite     " class="card-click-target" href="/s/kate_new_6">
 <span class="movies preordered-overlay-container id-preordered-overlay-container" style="display:none">
 <span class="preordered-label">?????????</span>
 </span>
 <span class="preview-overlay-container">
 </span>
 </a>]

>>> len(sp.select(".cover > a.card-click-target"))
2
```

Comment: I still get zero, `len(sp.select(".cover > a.card-click-target"))`

Comment: In this **exact** full code? Or did you use **only** the `len(sp` part?

Comment: Yes, I get full HTML code of page and after use rule

Comment: Also I tried your code, it returns me zero. Maybe problem is in verison? I use `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")`

Comment: which version of python/bs you use?

Comment: Python 3.5, bs - 4.5.1